# How to convert one list model to other list model for same variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I want to use one list variable in if condition which is declared initially with one model(List) but I want to assign another model(List)

```
  List<Teacher> list;
            if (WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReadData"] == "True")
            {

                list = answer.Where(x => x.Study.Contains(Name)).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                answer = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Student>(
                list = answer.Where(x => x.Study.Contains(Name)).ToList();
            }

> Getting error in else part- can not implicit convert type
> ..list<Teacher> to List<student>...
```

Comment: if you really need this - use not generic list, as `List<Teacher>` can't be `List<Student>` for sure.

Comment: Your query is returning a list of student, but you are trying to  assign this list to a list of teacher, this is the reason for the exception. Once you define a list of x you are not supposed to assign a list of y to it. There are different ways to do it, but it will depend on the specific scenario.

Comment: what are the different ways..?please suggest

Comment: Please see about [Automapper](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/some-useful-tips-while-using-automapper-in-C-Sharp/) if useful.

Comment: What is the type of `answer` before you reach the `if` as used in the then portion?